# jQuery coin slider plugin not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use the jQuery Coin Slider plugin on my page. I've downloaded and attached the latest Jquery to my header, along with all of the necessary Coin-slider files. When the latest version of jQuery didn't work I downloaded an olde version used in the instructions. However, the page simply stacks the images as if I had simply inserted tags.

The paths for all of the files are correct. I tried following his instructions to the letter on the "how to install" page, with no success.

I believe I am attaching the .js in the correct order, so I am not sure what the problem is.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/coin-slider.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="coin-slider-styles.css" type="text/css" />
<link href="styles/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<header id="mainHeading">
<div id="headingContent">
<h1>Header</h1>

</div> <!--Closes headingContent div-->
</header>

<article id="page-content">

<section>
<hgroup>
<h1></h1>
<h2></h2>
</hgroup>

</article>



<div id="coin-slider">
    <a href="img01_url" target="_blank">
        <img src='img01.jpg' >
    <span>
        Description for img01
    </span>
    </a>

    <a href="img02_url">
        <img src='img02.jpg' >
    <span>
        Description for img02
    </span>
    </a>

    <a href="img03_url">
        <img src='img03.jpg' >
    <span>
        Description for img03
    </span>
    </a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#coin-slider').coinslider({ width: 600, height: 300, navigation: false, delay: 5000, hoverPause: true });
});
</script>


</div> <!--Closes the main content-->

<footer id="mainFooter">
<p>Footer</p>
</footer> <!--Closes the footer-->

</div> <!--Closes the wrapper-->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the url for coin-slider-styles.css should not be pointing to the "css" subdirectory?

Comment: this should be a comment, as it does not answer the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you asking if the url for coin-slider-styles.css should be pointing to the styles folder?